# Task.Wait Deadlocks on a Task returned by Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm having a deadlock issue with some async code in 4.5. I read [Stephen Cleary's blog about preventing deadlocks that occur when the task captures the executing context](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) then in that same context you block by waiting for the Task. I tried to implement the solution but I'm still getting deadlocks and I'm not seeing why.

**Original Code**

Consuming Class:

```
private void Update(...)
    {
        //... do some stuff ... 
        _repository.Save(listing).Wait();
    }
```

Class that returns the Task:

```
protected override Task Save(...)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ... do some stuff ...
            _logger.Debug("All Done!!!");
        });
    }
```

**Modified Code**

Consuming Class:

```
private void Update(...)
    {
        //... do some stuff ... 
        _repository.Save(listing).Wait();
    }
```

Class that returns the Task:

```
protected override async Task Save(...)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ... do some stuff ...
            _logger.Debug("All Done!!!");
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Even in the modified version, where I am explicitly telling the awaitable Task not to bind to the context, I still get a deadlock.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` is just a workaround for when you *can't* use `await`. The best solution is definitely to make `Update` an `async Task` method; is there any reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: It looks like `Save` needs to `await` and your lambda `Task` needs to be `async`.

Comment: My Update method is a WebApi IHttpController. would it be better to make the controller return async void or async Task?
Thanks for the quick reply Stephen

Comment: Nevermind, I see you're blog gives a controller method example that returns async Task

Comment: What worries me is that we actually have other code consuming the same repository.Save method and then calling .Wait, but the other code isn't deadlocking, and is also not marked async. I did a search through our codebase and we have hundreds of .Wait calls all over the place, but this is the first time we've seen a deadlock. I'm trying to understand the problem as much as possible in case we start to see it in other places.

Comment: If the code was running outside of an ASP.NET context (i.e., in a regular threadpool context), then it wouldn't deadlock on `Wait`. (I still wouldn't recommend it for efficiency reasons, but it wouldn't deadlock).

Comment: I think your modified code shouldn't deadlock, could you post a complete (but short) sample code that demonstrates the deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the normal async await pattern

```
private async void Update(...)
{
    //... do some stuff ... 
   await _repository.Save(listing);
}

protected override async Task Save(...)
{

        ... do some stuff ...
        _logger.Debug("All Done!!!");
}
```

Comment: This is v old I know, but in the update the async void makes it hard to capture exceptions well, use async task if possible?